# Is is possible to send an e-mail using an Outlook form template but without the form scripts?

Tags: vbscript, outlook, outlook-form

If I send e-mails using an Outlook Form the form is being sent with all the scripts embedded. Can I remove them or just send the e-mail part?

The recipient see this in the preview pane: "The item contain active content that cannot be displayed in the Reading Pane. Open the item to read its contents." but I only want to send the content not the script and I want to run a script in the sender side.

I am escaping the add-on solution because they require an extra software installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the MAPI property UseTNEF in false is the solution. If you look at the "Sent Items" folder it will display the warning message but the received message does not display it.

Added an article about this solution: [Removing Active Content from E-Mails Sent via Outlook Forms](http://blog.nektra.com/main/2012/05/16/removing-active-content-from-e-mails-sent-via-outlook-forms/) it removes the winmail.dat attachment.